# Command + Tab sometimes does not switch to maximized window of app in another Space

Tags: spaces, mission-control

An app (such as Firefox) is opened and maximized on another Space. I'm on a separate Space, and then when I hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, to switch to Firefox, I can see its menu is displayed at the top of the screen, but it does not switch to the corresponding Space, and I can't see the app window.

Is there a way I can achieve the desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your Mac, go to System Preferences → Mission Control and see if **When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application** setting is enabled.

[image]